# Logarithmic scale in MuPAD

Tags: matlab, math-software

I had to plot a function, $e_n=\ln(n!)-n\ln(n)+n$, relative to a logarithmic scale. In MATLAB, I could do it simply by using `semilogx` but in MuPAD I can't find such a command. How can I do so?

Comment: `cordinattype=LogLog` works only for the y-axis. i look for a command that does the same but just for the y axis.

Comment: Is your function $e(n)$ or $e_n$? Since in the latter one we have a sequence of points instead.

Comment: its the latter.

Comment: See this recent question [Setting axis scale to logarithmic in MuPAD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413992/setting-axis-scale-to-logarithmic-in-mupad) over on StackOverflow. Seems like it may be an open question.

Comment: I saw it and even started bounty on it. I checked given solution and seems it doesn't work also...

Comment: If the given solution does not work, please give a detailled comment at that question including the problem you experience and the code you used.

Comment: I forgot to update here but I gave bounty for the solution and it solved the problem.thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As aforementioned I got answer for the question after offering bounty in stackoverflow. For good order, I'll quote the original answer:

> **CoordinateType** attribute allows us to switch between linear and logarithmic plots.
>
> By default CoordinateType is set to LinLin i.e. linear plots.
>   There are 3 cases of logarithmic 2d plots.
>
> **Semilog Plots**
>
> - **LinLog** - Linear coordinates are plotted along the horizontal axis, >logarithmic coordinates along the vertical axis. Functions of form y = >exp(c1*x+c2) become straight lines.
>     E.g. `plot(plot::Function2d(exp(x), x = 0 .. 100), CoordinateType = LinLog):`
>     [image]
> - ***LogLin*** - Logarithmic coordinates are plotted along the horizontal axis, >linear coordinates along the vertical axis. Functions of form y = c1 ln(x) + c2 >become straight lines.
>     E.g. `plot(plot::Function2d(5*log(10,x) + 8, x = 1 .. 100),CoordinateType = >LogLin):`
>
> [image]
>
> **Logarithmic Plots**
>
> - **LogLog** - Logarithmic coordinates are plotted along both axes. E.g. >`plot(plot::Function2d(sqrt(5*x) + x^4, x = 10^(-3) .. 10^3), CoordinateType = >LogLog):`
>
> [image]